# Is There Free Software that Uses the Same Commands Math Exchange Uses to Write Math Expressions?

Tags: math-software

Is there free downloadable software that allows me to write mathematical expressions with the same commands that are used to create them in math stack exchange? I tried texnic center, but their commands for creating mathematical expressions are difficult, messy, and not as fluid as the commands used here on the site.

Comment: What do you mean by difficult? What did you try on there that was different from math stack exchange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the markdown help for this site:

> Mathematics Stack Exchange uses MathJax to render LaTeX.

MathJax implements a small part of $\LaTeX$, so what you need to do is start learning $\LaTeX$ in a friendly environment.

You may find useful information at

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner

and

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides/

on the sister stackexchange site for $\TeX$ questions. You can also ask there as you learn.

Answer (score 0):

I use TeXworks and like it a lot.  If you're talking about something like that.